# syntax error when attempting to use bind vars in SQL queries in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, bind, sqlite3-ruby

I am using sqlite3 and attempting to pass bind variables into SQL statements in a command line application that I'm attempting as a replication of http://www.pangloss.com/seidel/shake_rule.html .  This is the management utility for adding/removing from the database.  I'm just trying to get an understanding of using SQL with Ruby and building a pen-and-paper rpg utility set for a DM whose game I'm currently playing.

```
db.execute ("INSERT INTO insults (position, string) VALUES (?, ?);",    cmd_args[1].to_i, cmd_args[2])

db.execute("SELECT * FROM insults WHERE position = ? AND string = ?;", cmd_args[1].to_i, cmd_args[2]) do |output|
  puts output
end
```

The first query causes a syntax error "unexpected ',', expecting ')'" and more errors which follow, but they disappear when I comment this line out.

The latter query does not seem fundamentally different, but it causes no errors when I comment out the former.  It still does not output anything when I set the cmd_args array values manually.  The database has some test elements in it, i.e. "1|test" which do not output, though no error is thrown.

Comment: are you passing three arguments on the command line?

Comment: It's actually a badly named variable I suppose.  It's a split string.  The second problem was actually part of the first.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a space between the method name and the opening parenthesis. Your first one:

```
db.execute ("INSERT INTO insults (position, string) VALUES (?, ?);",    cmd_args[1].to_i, cmd_args[2])
```

is interpreted more like this:

```
x = ("INSERT ....", cms_args[1].to_i, cmd_args[2])
db.execute x
```

but constructs like `(a, b, c)` aren't legal Ruby syntax in that context and there's your syntax error.

Your second one:

```
db.execute("SELECT * ...", cmd_args[1].to_i, cmd_args[2]) do |output|
  puts output
end
```

should work fine so, presumably, your WHERE clause doesn't match anything so you don't get any results. Examine the contents of `cmd_args` and make sure that:

1. You don't have any stray whitespace.
2. Your arguments really are in `cmd_args[1..2]` rather than `cmd_args[0..1]`.

Comment: That feeling where you're relieved and frustrated at its simplicity.  Thank you for the added understanding of just why that space caused trouble.  I'll have to keep looking for the second problem, but thanks.

Comment: @bismuth: The space issue is related to being able to call methods without parentheses in Ruby.